# How do i repeat an if statement until it's false in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

So i have this code that is supposed to generate random words of length the user decides with these conditions:

```
[1] Every other letter is a random vowel (letter + vowel + letter + vowel...etc)
[2] Two vowels cannot meet together (ie: bout, caravaa)
```

I got over the first part condition, and the second condition needs some edit.
i used an if statement to check if `letter1` or `letter2` happen to be vowels, and if true generate generate different letters. Problem is those newly generated letters have a chance of being vowels. How do i keep repeating the if statement until it's false? `(Letter1 and Letter2 are not vowels)`

```
import java.util.Random;

public class NickName_1
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
{
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    int letterNum = 6;
    Random rn = new Random();
    char letter1 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    char letter2 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    char vowel;


    while (true)
    {
        //Ask user for word's length and store it
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please enter the length of the word in letters: ");
        letterNum = scanner.nextInt();

        vowel = vowels[(int)(Math.random() * 5)];

        for (int i = 0; i < (letterNum / 3); i++)
        {
            letter1 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
            letter2 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
            vowel = vowels[(int)(Math.random() * 5)];

            // if letter1 or letter2 equal a vowel then regenerate letters
            if (letter1 == 'a' || letter1 == 'u' || letter1 == 'i' || letter1 == 'e' || letter1 == 'o' || 
                letter2 == 'a' || letter2 == 'u' || letter2 == 'i' || letter2 == 'e' || letter2 == 'o')

            {
                letter1 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                letter2 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
            }
                System.out.print(letter1 + "" + vowel + "" + letter2);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Understand that an if block is not a loop and does not repeat on it's own. So to answer your question -- You don't. You use a while loop and condition to repeat blocks of code.

Comment: How can i use the while loop and give it the conditions in my case ? @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Don't ask -- try and test.

Comment: Can i use the while statement like 
while (iletter1 == 'a' || letter1 == 'u' ||...etc)

Comment: @JawnyThompson Why not?

Comment: @JawnyThompson But remember, just changing `if` to `while` would not fulfill both the criterias you have told in the question.

Comment: @manetsus i tried it and it seemed to work. Can you explain why :)

Comment: @JawnyThompson What did you meant by `Every other letter`? I assumed you told `Every even letter` from your explanation `(letter + vowel + letter + vowel...etc)`. Is it guaranteed that user would give you a number multiple of 3?

Comment: @manetsus
You're right if the user enter a number that isn't a multiple of three it just prints out the previous multiple. So if i enter a numbers 4,5 it prints out 3 letters. I coudn't solve this issue.

Comment: @JawnyThompson But you should! However, I would propose a solution, until then, try yourself.

Comment: @manetsus Thank you i'm trying to solve it as of the moment.

Comment: @JawnyThompson See my solution. Thanks.

Comment: Ahahahaha, the amount of ignorance i had back then, can't believe i asked that only 1 year ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned about two criteria. But the code does not fulfill them even replacing `if` with `while`.

I have modified your code so that it could fulfill your criteria. I want to point out the major things below:

1. You are trying to print 3 letters at a time. That means input should be multiple of 3, otherwise the program would fail. I would suggest you to print a letter at a time.
2. Your need is `letter + vowel + letter + vowel...`, but you are printing `letter + vowel + letter + letter + vowel + letter...`. Rather I recommend keep a `boolean` variable and change it in every turn, check whether it is the turn of vowel or consonant, then do the corresponding work in their own code blocks.
3. It is a bad practice to end up a program with exception. Thats why I have added a `try-catch` and wrapped the input in it.
4. To make your code more convenient, [Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate) suggested a good way in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842531/how-do-i-repeat-an-if-statement-until-its-false-in-java/39842843#comment66975054_39842602) -- *"Make a function or set and check for membership"*. I would suggest you to make another array for consonants as you made for vowels and pick a random one.

[Here](http://ideone.com/wMYvGv) is the modified code in ideone. Below is your version of the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class NickName_1
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        int letterNum = 6;
        Random rn = new Random();
        char letter = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
        boolean shouldCons = true;
        char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

        while (true)
        {
            //Ask user for word's length and store it
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Please enter the length of the word in letters: ");
            try{
                letterNum = scanner.nextInt();
            }catch(Exception e){
                break;
            }
    
            for (int i = 0; i < letterNum; i++, shouldCons^=true)
            {
                if(shouldCons) {
                    letter = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    while (letter == 'a' || letter == 'u' || letter == 'i' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'o')
                    {
                        letter = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
                    }
                }
                else letter = vowels[(int)(Math.random() * 5)];
              
                System.out.print(letter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks so much for the insightful answer =D. I learned a lot from it.
I just have one question what did you use the shouldCons for? and when does it not = true?...Also, I have been learning java for 2 weeks now and i haven't dug into functions yet.

Comment: Oh so the shouldCons in the for loop is gonna keep alternating between "true" and "false" and thus giving a letter, each time it's true, and a vowel if it is false.

Comment: @JawnyThompson Exactly, you learnt it yourself! Happy Learning! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your if statement with a while statement.

```
while (letter1 == 'a' || letter1 == 'u' || letter1 == 'i' || letter1 == 'e' || letter1 == 'o' || 
       letter2 == 'a' || letter2 == 'u' || letter2 == 'i' || letter2 == 'e' || letter2 == 'o')
{
    letter1 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    letter2 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
}
```

Update:

Looking at your code, it would be much better to check each of the letters separately, otherwise letter1 could be getting consonants but because letter 2 is not it continues changing both of them.

```
while (letter1 == 'a' || letter1 == 'u' || letter1 == 'i' || letter1 == 'e' || letter1 == 'o')
{
    letter1 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
}
while (letter2 == 'a' || letter2 == 'u' || letter2 == 'i' || letter2 == 'e' || letter2 == 'o')
{
    letter2 = (char) (rn.nextInt(26) + 'a');
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work. Thank you and to all the guys that answered me. So now the wile loop will keep repeating until the conditions between brackets are false?
Also, i don't understand why people downvote questions, that seem helpful to the asker.
PS. i will accept the answer once i can.

Comment: That is correct, it will not exit until all of the conditions are false (and therefore both letters are not vowels).

Comment: Thank you, i added the edit, as it would be ore convenient as you mentioned.

Comment: Even better, add the vowels to a set, and check for membership, or make a function to hide away all the `||`s and reduce duplication. If you ever see yourself writing the same code in multiple spot, make that code into a function, and use the function.